# Using webhint with angular7

Tags: node.js, angular7, wai-aria

I am trying to incorporate webhint which is a linting tool that 
will help you with your site's accessibility, speed, security and more, 
by checking your code for best practices and common errors.

So its installation is as follows :-

1. npm install hint --save-dev
2. npm create hintrc  (creates a config file)
3. then I add hint to scripts in package json
   "hint" : hint
4. I run the local server using ng serve in one cmd
5. And I run webhint in other cmd using 
   npm run hint -- http://localhost:4200

I wanted to run the ng serve/build along with npm run hint.
I tried steps on link https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/development-flow-integration/local-server/

I also tried &&, | and concurrency but all failed.

What I want is to run both these ng serve/build and npm run hint using one command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When an angular application with multiple components is run and webhint is run, the html or json formatters show errors but line numbers are column -1 and row -1.

Most likely this is because the html of the page is generated on the client side so the line/col don't make a lot of sense as it is generated dynamically. If you tell the browser to so the pages code you only obtain the initial html, and if you go to the elements panel in the devtools line and column don't have sense there.

The errors should have the html of the element with the error and that should hopefully help you identify the template with the issue.

That said, we have plans to improve this experience but need to finish a few things first.

> How does webhint traverse the code using routes or urls so I can better understand it ?

When using Chrome or jsdom we wait until the page is loaded and then analyze all the html while keeping track of all the network requests. In the case of the local we analyze all the files in the folder passed as a parameter.

> npm run all and concurrency don't work for me. ng serve only keeps running.

Do you have the code somewhere so we can take a look? Enabling the concurrency should launch all tasks simultaneously. Maybe it's a question of adding a delay in webhint or something similar.

Thanks!